# Confluent-Kafka Python - Describe consumer groups (to get the lag of each consumer group)

Tags: python, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, confluent-kafka-python

I want to get the details of the consumer group using confluent-kafka. The cli equivalent of  that is
`

```
./kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server XXXXXXXXX:9092 --describe --group my-group
```

My end goal is to get the value of lag from the output. Is there any method in confluent-kafka python API to get these details. There is a method in the [java API](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/clients/javadocs/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/admin/Admin.html#describeConsumerGroups-java.util.Collection-) but I couldn't find it in python API.

I tried using the [describe_configs](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/clients/confluent-kafka-python/html/index.html#confluent_kafka.admin.AdminClient.describe_configs) method in the adminClient API but it ended up throwing kafkaException with following details

> This most likely occurs because of a request being malformed by the client library or the message was sent to an incompatible broker. See the broker logs for more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For now I have come up with the following solution. It's a work around to get the combined lag of a consumer group

```
 def get_lag(topic,numPartitions):
    diff = list()
    for i in range(numPartitions):
        topic_partition = TopicPartition(topic, partition=i)
        low, high = consumer.get_watermark_offsets(topic_partition)
        currentList = consumer.committed([topic_partition])
        current = currentList[0].offset
        diff.append(high-current)
    return sum(diff) # Combined Lag
```

Comment: It's not a workaround. Using the consumer class is the only way

Comment: I'd use consumer.list_topic to get metadata for finding partitions, instead of passing numPartitions.  Also you have to check high < 0 to ignore such partition, also check if .offset < 0 for high - low as lag.  Personally, I added admin_client to get host name where (topic, partition) consumers are running to identify which host is having problem.